# Precision decreases with each epoch in CNN

Tags: machine-learning, keras, cnn

I've built the following CNN that is used to classify a binary classification set (something a like cats or dogs):

```
    self.opt = SGD(lr=0.0001)

    self.model.add(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=3, input_shape=(100, 100, 3), padding='same'))
    self.model.add(BatchNormalization())
    self.model.add(Activation(self.activation))
    self.model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))

    self.model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation=self.activation, padding='same'))
    self.model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))

    self.model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation=self.activation, padding='same'))
    self.model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))

    self.model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation=self.activation, padding='same'))
    self.model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))

    self.model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    self.model.add(Flatten())
    self.model.add(Dense(150))
    self.model.add(Activation(self.activation))
    self.model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    self.model.add(BatchNormalization())
    self.model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    self.model.summary()
    self.model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  optimizer=self.opt,
                  metrics=[self.precision])
```

Sadly, my training seems to be doing very badly as the precision is decreasing with each epoch:

[image]

What are some common issues when this behaviour is noticed?

Is the most likely cause that my training data is biased for one class? Right now I have 25% class 1 and 75% class 2.

How much does the size of the pictures influence the performance? As of now, all pictures are size 100x100. Does increasing the size lets say to 400x400 make the CNN more capable of detecting the features?

Additional code:

Loading the Images:

```
def convert_image_to_array(files,relpath):
    images_as_array=[]
    len_files = len(files)
    i = 0
    print("---ConvImg2Arr---")
    print("---STARTING---")
    for file in files:
        # Convert to Numpy Array
        images_as_array.append(img_to_array(load_img(relpath+file, target_size=(soll_img_shape, soll_img_shape)))/255)
        if i == int(len_files*0.2):
            print("20% done")
        if i == int(len_files*0.5):
            print("50% done")
        if i == int(len_files*0.8):
            print("80% done")

        i +=1
    print("---DONE---")
    return images_as_array

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.preprocessing import image
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

cnn = nn.NeuralNetwork()
cnn.compile()

##### Load Images to train, test and validate

x_train = np.array(convert_image_to_array(X_train,"images/processed/"))
x_test = np.array(convert_image_to_array(X_test,"images/processed/"))
```

Also the prediction metric:

```
def precision(self, y_true, y_pred):
    '''Calculates the precision, a metric for multi-label classification of
    how many selected items are relevant.
    '''
    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    predicted_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)))
    precision = true_positives / (predicted_positives + K.epsilon())
    return (precision)
```

Comment: What is `K.epsilon()` in your precision function (btw you should not call this precision you should rather call it accuracy)? Why don't you simply calculate `accuracy = true_positives / sample_size` ?

Comment: why you do not do augmentation to enlarge your class 1 size? maybe it helps to improve your results

Comment: @honar.cs what do you mean with this?